# xargs not splitting on whitespace from aws cli output

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, xargs, jmespath

This commands returns all the AWS regions separated by whitespace:

```
aws ec2 describe-regions --query 'Regions[*].RegionName' --output text

eu-north-1  ap-south-1  eu-west-3   eu-west-2   eu-west-1   ap-northeast-2  ap-northeast-1  sa-east-1   ca-central-1    ap-southeast-1  ap-southeast-2  eu-central-1    us-east-1   us-east-2   us-west-1   us-west-2
```

I'm trying to pipe this to xargs but it's seeing it as a single string:

```
aws ec2 describe-regions --query 'Regions[*].RegionName' --output text | gxargs -I {} aws cloudformation list-stacks --region {}

Invalid endpoint: https://cloudformation.eu-north-1 ap-south-1  eu-west-3   eu-west-2   eu-west-1   ap-northeast-2  ap-northeast-1  sa-east-1   ca-central-1    ap-southeast-1  ap-southeast-2  eu-central-1    us-east-1   us-east-2   us-west-1   us-west-2.amazonaws.com
gxargs: aws: exited with status 255; aborting
```

gxargs is just gnu xargs (I'm on Mac).

Also, tried this to use jmespath to create a string from an array with a specific delimiter (which I could use with xargs):

```
aws ec2 describe-regions --query 'Regions[*].join(",",@.RegionName)'
In function join(), invalid type for value: None, expected one of: ['string'], received: "null"
```

EDIT: just following up, this is what I wound up with. It insists on throwing an error when it doesn't find a stack- probably the same for other aws cli commands

```
aws ec2 describe-regions --query 'Regions[*].RegionName' --output text | gxargs -n 1 sh -c 'aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name findme --region $0 || true'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's `man xargs` for `-I`:

> `-I replace-str` 
> Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input.  Also,  **unquoted  blanks
> do not terminate input items**; instead the separator is the newline character.  Implies -x and -L 1.

You can use `xargs -n 1 aws cloudformation list-stacks --region` instead

Comment: why does `-n 1` work? the man page for `-n` is confusing me, I can understand what its doing

Comment: It's to only run the command with one region at a time, since I imagine running with multiple regions won't work no matter how you split them

Comment: I know that I mean how is xargs parsing it? I thought by default xargs split by whitespace and run once for each item. `-n 1` means use whitespace as the delimiter?

Comment: No. `-I` means "stop using whitespace as a delimiter". `-n` does not affect delimiters, so here it would default to using whitespace.

Comment: Is there a way to use whitespace as a delimiter and also get a reference to the word like you can when using -I MYWORD?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. In general it's better to avoid the whitespace splitting mode since it's fragile and surprising with regards to quotes, and instead make sure the input is `\n` or `\0` separated.